# how to programmatically add ToggleButton to specific listView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, togglebutton

I know how to add a ToggleButton to ALL of the listView rows. But how do i add a ToggleButton to only ONE specific listView row?

Im populating my listView with an ArrayAdapter like so

```
ListView mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSetting);
mlistView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
          new String[] {"Rate @ME App", "Feedback", "Block", "Terms of Service", "Push Notifications", "Sign Out"}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a layout file containing a togglebutton
2. Create a [customAdapter](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom) by extending an Adapter e.g. ArrayAdapter
3. Override the getView() method
4. Implement the viewHolder pattern to improve performance
5. Add logic to the getView() method to handle the togglebutton

Here is some pseudocode

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
         // Do inflation here, use a viewholder pattern to improve performance

         // Add logic to handle togglebutton, view being togglebutton
         if(items.get(position).equals(something){
            view.setVisibilty(View.Visible);
         }else{
             view.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
         }
     }
```

Comment: Im a little confused on number 2. Create a customAdapter by extending an Adapter e.g. ArrayAdapter

Im coming over from iOS if that helps any. And i understand the concept of what your saying. Just confused on number 2, and a little on 4 but ive seen a few topics on that and can understand that as well.

Comment: If have added a link to a tutorial (this tutorial covers most of the points mentioned), hope this clears it up for you, if not comment below